# Creating many routes in ASP.Net MVC 2 will slow down my app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am creating a private forum engine a bit like Stackoverflow, however, the forum will be private. For the question and answers I will be using a lot of routes for all kind of activeties. Can anyone tell me if I create a considerable number of routes in my Global.asax if it will slow down my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think creating many routes can get you in trouble easily, not performance wise in the first place but MVC getting confused which route to take.

If you stick to the action/controller pattern 9 of 10 times the default route will suffice.

I only use custom routes when i want an url shortcut that looks nice.

Comment: I am putting the more especific routes first. I think this will avoid this problem.

Comment: For more specific I mean that match exactly the URL desired.